# subtract values Python36

Tags: python-3.x

i try to subtract value from requests.get("http://link/test.txt")

test.txt= 5

and i try to subtract 5 - 1

my code :

```
count1 = requests.get('http://link/test.txt')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
await client.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name='test : '+ str(count1.text) - int(1), type=1))
```

i want to get 5 - 1 = [Final result to be : 4] as bot status "test : 4"

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'

Comment: Convert that `4` into `str`

Comment: i tried, and good unknown error

Comment: i updated the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the string to a number:

```
count1 = requests.get('http://link/test.txt')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name='test : ' + str(int(count1.text) - 1), type=1))
```

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int', {if i use str},,,, TypeError: must be str, not int {if i use int}.

Comment: @Darzy08 convert the result of the subtraction back to `str`. I updated my answer

Comment: big thanks, eventually i got how it work, thanks for that great info